# Adding URL adresses to views in SAPUI5

Tags: shell, navigation, view, sapui5

I have SAPUI5 application where I am using Shell. I have different views in my Shell and I am able to navigate from one view to another. The problem is that I don't know how can I create or change URL adress to each view. I need to set URL adresses to be able to use "back" button in a browser. I want to add unique URL adress to each view inside my Shell to use "back" and "forward" buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [simple sap.ui.core.routing.Router example](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/samples/routing/mobile/index.html#/9) it shows how to easily set up and use routes and a hash changer with an app Shell container.

[sap.ui.core.routing](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.html) is a javascript routes utilty, it handles URL changes and dispatches control  based on pattern logic to views and event handlers, part of routing is HashChanger and History functionality.

if you are using the desktop shell this [routing example with sap.ui.ux3.Shell](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/samples/routing/index.html#/example2)

A lot of examples use jQuery.sap.history.js IMO it doesn't properly support bookmarks and has limited features which means you have to use it with other techniques

Comment: This is actually pretty neat! I wasn't aware the Router utility could handle URL changes as well, and better than the sap.history.js

Comment: Thanks Jasper_07, it is very useful inormation!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, History API presents in modern browsers only. For IE6+ I recommend you to use "hashchange" event of window:

```
    function router(){
        var sViewName = window.location.hash.slice(1),
            oView = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sViewName) || new sap.ui.view.XMLView({id : sViewName, viewName : sViewName});
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("uxShell").setContent(oView);
        return false;
    }

if("onhashchange" in window){
    if(window.attachEvent){ //IE8
        attachEvent('onhashchange', router);
    } else if(window.addEventListener){ //IE9+, Chrome, Opera, Firefox
        addEventListener('hashchange', router);
    }
} else { //IE6-7
    var oldHref = window.location.hash;
    setInterval(function(){
       var newHref = window.location.hash;
       if(oldHref !== newHref){
          oldHref = newHref;
          router();
       }
    }, 100);
}
```

But to make it work you need to set `href` property to navigation items like this: `#catalog.viewName`